# Where is app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() and OpenIdConnectMiddleware in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: asp.net-core

**Context**

I am trying to migrate an application which uses `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` but this extension method not found in package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` 
The actual source of this extension method uses the class `OpenIdConnectMiddleware` which also seems to be gone.

**Question**

How can I migrate this application?

Comment: That was deprecated with the release of ASP.NET Core 2.0. See [Migrate authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.0#openid-connect-oidc-authentication).

Comment: Kirk, thx, my bad In  case you post this as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your startup file to the example below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookies";
            })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ClientId = "mvc-client";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret-key";
                    options.ResponseType = "id_token token";

                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                });
        }
```